# How might single windows be made negative for the purposes of accessibility?

Tags: mate, accessibility, color-management

Previously I was able to set single windows to turn to negative colours using CompizConfig Settings Manager. One could enable an accessibility plugin called "Negative" to switch the window in focus to inverse colours. This is helpful for people with certain visual conditions and needs.

How might this be achieved on Ubuntu 20.04 with the MATE desktop environment?